# QField Cloud and QGIS: after pushing new data from my tablet to the cloud, they don't appear in my PC version of the project

Tags: qgis, qfield, cloud-gis

My geopackaged QGIS-project is successfully uploaded to QField using the Cloud-method. Adding items(trees) work well on the tablet and I can push the added items to the cloud. But they don't seem to download from the cloud to the QGIS program on my PC.